# Matching "..." = "..." in Python via Regex

Tags: python, regex, equation, quotation-marks

I'm quite bad with Regexp stuff, so I can't figure out why this does not work. I simply want to match the two strings within an assignment/equation, something like this:

`"string1" = "string2"`

In this case, I'd expect "string1" and "string2" to be matched (without the quotation marks). I tried the following regex, which works in a regex tester I found on the web, but not in Python:

`("[^"]*").=.("[^"]*")`

In Python it would look like this:

`matches = re.findall(r'("[^"]*").=.("[^"]*")', line)`

But like I said, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `print repr(line)` print?

Comment: The line mixed with \x00 between each character. Is this some kind of encoding problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the quotation marks outside the capture group, if you don't want them to be part of your matches:

```
>>> matches = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)".=."([^"]*)"', line)
>>> matches
[('string1', 'string2')]
```

Also, since you have space around your "=", you should just match a space. A dot "." matches any character.

Comment: Strangely, this works fine on the interactive CLI for me, but not in the script I want to use it with. I read the lines via fileinput.input(...). I tried matching the newline character '\n' as well, but to no effect.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it turns out my problem was with the encoding of the file I read from, which was UTF-16. I had to pass `openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-16")` to fileinput.input(..), now it seems to work!